# add comment on order confirmation mail

Tags: magento-1.9

i'd like to put some comment on order confirmation mail.
it's not for customer but for me(sales person)
I want to write some comment on magento admin and want it to be shown in 
order confirmation mail.

Is there anyway to do that? or is there any good extension for it?

Thank you

Comment: The order confirmation email is sent out immediately after the order is placed. If you want this comment to be sent out then it would have to be the same for all of your customers. Also, Magento does not send a different email to the administrator than to the user. So this would be difficult. What kind of a comment are you looking to send? Would that be something dynamic or the same text for every email?

Answer (score 3):

Go to order email template

**app/local/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html**

**app/local/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html**

add your **phtml** file in email template

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/test.phtml' order=$order}}
```

in your **app/design/frontend/base/default/email/order/test.phtml**

**add you logic in phtml file** and  you can order object by

```
<?php $order=$this->getOrder(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be a custom extension. I'm not aware of any existing extensions that do that.